# Add element with class in Angular 2 directive

Tags: angular, typescript

I know I can add an element to an Angular 2 directive like this:

`this._renderer.createElement(this._el.nativeElement.parentNode, 'div');`

How do I set the class of that added element and get a reference to it to remove at a later date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did that through.

```
let ele = this.renderer.createElement(this.el.nativeElement.parentNode, "div");
this.renderer.setElementClass(ele, "my-class", true);
```